# Grey spots on Clematis leaves

Tags: diseases, leaves, fungus, climbers, clematis

One of my clematis Tekla stopped growing a month ago and sort of froze in time. Its leaves started having grey spots and new growth leaves dried out as you can see from the picture below. Initially I thought that it is a clematis wilt, but reading through variety of resources does not confirm this fact since leaves don't turn black and fall and they don't fade but rather being covered with grey spots. In addition it has been like this for a month while I read that clematis wilt damages the branches within days so must be a different fungus? Can anyone help identifying what it might be?

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: Is the plant in a pot or in the ground and how long have you had it? Can you check the underside of the leaves to see if there's anything unusual  there....and which part of the UK are you in? How much sun does it get?

Comment: @Bamboo thanks. Clematis is in the ground, we purchased it in September, in March it had its fresh growth which you can see from the picture. Underside of the leaves is actually normal green, nothing unusual. I live in London. The clematis is on the West facing wall which gets a lot of sun after 2PM.

Comment: Have you been using the same fertilizing  routine as you did for the other clematis with purple areas on the leaves? How close to the wall is this planted?

Comment: @Bamboo yes. It was planted 30 cm away from the wall. But if you are thinking the root cause is the same, why the reaction of plants is different? Is it base on clematis type? I have other clematis plants that seem growing fine in the ground.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure what the problem is, but would offer the same solution - stop feeding and increase watering. The symptoms on the leaves don't fit any of the usual problems a clematis might suffer, so it's probaby environmental, i.e, the growing conditions. If it gets a lot worse or other symptoms  appear, please post again.